# using Jquery to controll two dropdown lists (pre-populated)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists, html-select

I'm having some issues with a two-list dropdown-chooser. I previously tried to arrange it with select-options, but I ran into major problems when I tried to dynamically hide the options.

Another benefit with using ul-li is that I can then style it more cross-browser friendly and also easier (as I understand it from other stackoverflow-questions).

Other solutions I have found all require some form of loading, such as AJAX, to populate the second list, but that is not an option here so the whole list will be pre-loaded. Classes and other attributes can be added/removed.

```
<ul>
    <li>Volvo</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Ford</li>
    <li>Jeep</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>[Choose Brand first]</li> <!-- visible if nothing chosen in 1st -->
    <li>[Choose model]</li> <!-- visible for all brands -->
    <li class="volvo">S80</li>
    <li class="volvo">V70</li>
    <li class="volvo">XC90</li>
    <li class="audi">A8</li>
    <li class="audi">A6</li>
    <li class="audi">A4</li>
    <li class="bmw">X1</li>
    <li class="bmw">M6</li>
    <li class="ford">fiesta</li>
    <li class="ford">Fiesta</li>
    <li class="ford">Mustang</li>
    <li class="ford">Explorer</li>
    <li class="jeep">Wrangler</li>
    <li class="jeep">Cherokee</li>  
</ul>
```

What I want is:

1. For the two lists to behave similar to two dropdown-list (select-option). I tried a few solutions for a single list, but I was never able to get it to work properly when using two lists on the same page.. (for example this: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/202/)
2. For only the options in the second list with a specific class to be shown based on first list-option

For example:

- If no choice is made in first list, then no car models are shown in
  second list
- If 'Volvo' is chosen in first list, then only car models with class Volvo are shown in second list

If convenient, I would be very greatful for a jsfiddle solution.

Thanks beforehand

Comment: For example, you can add class to your ul list and use a code like this: `$(".first-ul > li").on("click", function() { var cl = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(".second-ul").children().filter(function(i){
        if($(this).hasClass(cl)) return $(this);
    }).css({'color':'red'});
});`

Comment: thanks, but I seem to not get it working fully? Can you see what I've done wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/codin/GRF2d/

Comment: Chose a Jquery lib in your fiddle and indent correctly the function, for me works ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this does the trick pretty well: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/221/
I won't say that the code is optimized the best it could but it works on all the latest browsers (Safari, Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 10, 9, and 8,7 [in quirks mode]).
What it does is:

- Show the second `ul` when an option in the first one is selected
- Re-display [SELECT] in the second `ul` when the value is changed in the first one
- Only display the values in the second `ul` when the `li data-value` of a first ul equals the classes of the li's in the second ul.

I also put the whole function code in a variable that is called afterwards.

Basically, all you have to do, is change the 2 handlers ( thisDropDown, nextDropDown ) to the ul id's on your page.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: great solution, thanks a lot for the help! I just made som simple tweaks to it to get more useability regarding hiding the menues (for example when clicking outside the active menu etc) then it was just what I was looking for